# WooCommerce тема

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу изучить плагин WooCommerce для Wordpress. Нужно в этом нормально разобраться, особенно - как создать свою тему (не брать готовую) под WooCommerce. Ищу нормальные уроки по этому, но найти ничего нормального не могу, мне подходит вариант и по-английски, но там тоже не нашел (. Если кто то знает хорошие уроки - киньте ссылку или название.) !

Comment: Зачем вам своя тема?)) Вы в самом деле считаете, что способны сделать нечто лучшее, чем Storefront?

Comment: Что бы нормально разобраться - нужно долго разбираться с тем что уже есть. А всё есть в документации. Делать свои темы вообще не нужно

Comment: > мне подходит вариант и по-английски, но там тоже не нашел Неужели? Вначале изучаем http://developer.wordpress.org/ После этого https://docs.woocommerce.com/

Comment: то есть мне нужно брать готовую тему и потом уже ее кастомизировать под свой дезайн (простите, я в плагине ничего не знаю поэтому вопросы могут быть глупы для тех кто знает)

Comment: Обращайтесь почаще к кодексу WP.
Еще на хабре есть много хорошего материал по теме.
Шпаргалочка тоже лишней не будет: [шпаргалка](http://anton.shevchuk.name/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/wordpress_-_template_designer_cheatsheet_ru.pdf)

Comment: До кастомизации тему нужно много чего знать. А ты даже адресов документации не знаешь, гуглить не умеешь (не знаешь что искать) Не говоря уже об основах ВП и тем более WC.

Comment: Ида чтобы заниматься WC вначале нужно изучить ВП. Хотя бы на уровне уверенного владения функциями, пониманием структуры темы, шаблонов, и тд

Comment: Берите Storefront, создавайте от нее дочернюю тему. На следующем этапе разбирайтесь, как она устроена - смотрите код в файлах php и js.

Comment: К сожалению, поиск уроков и прочих туториалов - оффтопик. Переформулируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы он не сводился к поиску литературы.

Answer (score 1):

Не начинайте с нуля.

1. Установите тему Storefront и [создайте дочернюю к ней](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/).
2. Читайте [документацию к плагину](https://docs.woocommerce.com/).
3. Используйте [картинки по хукам](https://businessbloomer.com/category/woocommerce-tips/visual-hook-series/).
4. Ищите помощи здесь и на английском SO.

Но если вы ещё не делали дочерние темы для вордпресса - не беритесь за вукоммерс. Сделайте несколько проектов без него, пока не выучите базовые функции и хуки вордпресса наизусть.

Comment: "Но если вы ещё не делали дочерние темы для вордпресса - не беритесь за вукоммерс." - только за это плюсую))